# get hour/timezone on azure server

Tags: time, azure

How can you know which hour/timezone is used on azure (within a worker role for instance) ? how does it work when servers are loadbalanced ? Would you use some kind of ntp server to synchronize instead ?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406194/azure-time-zone-and-javascriptserializer-object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Azure servers all run on UTC Time.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgolpe/archive/2010/12/29/windows-azure-date-time-and-locale.aspx for more information.

Comment: ...and the time seems to be quite frequently set. Try changing it!

Answer (score 0):

I created service in Azure and code snippet to get actual Azure time

http://azuretime.azurewebsites.net/datetimeoffset

```
private async Task<DateTimeOffset> GetAzureTimeAsync()
{
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        return DateTimeOffset.Parse(await client.GetStringAsync("http://azuretime.azurewebsites.net/datetimeoffset")).ToUniversalTime();        
    }   
}
```

[Get Azure Time](http://azuretime.azurewebsites.net/)